# Crop video from QTKit

Tags: objective-c, video, video-capture, qtkit

I'm using the OSX QTKit sample code from here: http://bit.ly/mAaHGI

I'd like to crop the video, both on the screen and the saved file, to simulate different aspect ratios. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit more involved than just calling a crop method, but Core Video allows you to manipulate the video stream. You can find the Core Video Programming Guide here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreVideo/CVProg_Intro/CVProg_Intro.html